# How can I save an avconv/ffmpeg command for later?

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I'd like to save my entire avconv command with options so that I can reuse it without typing it in every time. I would still need to specify the input and output filenames. How do I do this? I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: put the command in a text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
avconv <your options here> $1 $2
```

`$1` and `$2` are arguments that will be passed to `avconv`. The idea is to replace input file by `$1` and output file by `$2`. Then you'll run your script with `./script.sh input.mp4 output.mkv` for example.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
avconv -f alsa -i pulse -f video4linux2 -channel 1 -s 768x576 -i /dev/video0 -deinterlace -c:v mpeg2video -b:v 4000k -b:a 192k $1
```

And I run it like:

```
./record.sh video.mpg
```

`video.mpg` is passed through `$1` to `avconv`.

Comment: Do I need to place the $1 and $2 in the place they would appear in the command? like 'avconv -i $1 <options> $2'

Comment: @MikeJerome yes, in the place where the filenames should be.